# How to bind a boolean bean property with radio button in Struts 2

Tags: jsp, struts2, boolean, ognl

I have a backend POJO (say `MyBean`) containing a boolean property `Boolean isValid`.

I'm populating a list of `MyBean` to display on the JSP.

Now I want to have a radio button beside each `MyBean`, so that user can select any one of them as valid bean.

It's not the case that I want a radio to choose among a pre-defined list of values (as `list` is mandatory attribute in `s:radio`).

Can anybody suggest how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The boolean property should have a getter

```
public Boolean isValid() { return this.isValid; }
```

once the list is returned you can use OGNL projection to filter only `isValid` values. Or you don't need it at all if you use `listkey` and `listValue` attributes.

See examples from Struts docs:

> In this example, a radio control is displayed with a list of genders.
>   The gender list is built from attribute `id=genders`. The framework
>   calls `getGenders()` which will return a `Map`.
>
> For examples using `listKey` and `listValue` attributes, see the section select tag. 
>   The default  selected one will be determined (in this case) by the `getMale()` method
>   in the action class which should return a value similar to the key of
>   the `getGenders()` map if that particular gender is to be selected.
>
> ```jsp
> <s:action name="GenderMap" var="genders"/>
> <s:radio label="Gender" name="male" list="#genders.genders"/>
> <@s.radio name="car" list={"ford": "Ford Motor Co", "toyota": "Toyota"} listKey="key" listValue="value" />
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! but I have already tried this. This radio (under a iterator) will only work if their "name" is same. But I can not keep the name same for all beans since this "name" is used while submitting the page (each radio must maps to any particular bean in backend whereas they have "only one selection" relation in front end.